# Why a linearly independent set of vectors must not contain the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Why is it necessary for a linearly independent set of vectors to not contain the zero vector? I am looking with the definition perspective i.e. why do we define linear independence in this way?

Comment: Hint: $a0 = 0$ even for $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Do you know the definition of independent vectors?

Comment: A linearly independen set of vectors cannot contain a subset of vectors that is *not* linearly independent. So the set $\{0\}$ is not allowed to be a subset of it (see the hint of @Tobias).

Comment: Thanks all for the comments but I was more looking with the definition perspective i.e. Why is it necessary that a set of vectors is linearly independent if and only if it does not contain zero vector, and accordingly the definition arises !

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this was put on hold, what OP asked is perfectly clear: "*Why do we define linearly independence the way we do*?"

Comment: @user3672145 It's not true that a set of nonzero vectors is linearly independent, in general. What's true is that vectors in a linearly independent set are nonzero.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Why $a\neq $? Take $a=0$. Then, $0.0=0$.

Comment: @Kahler Because that would not show anything.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How? Can you example?

Comment: @Kahler because of how linearly (in)dependent is defined.

Answer (score 6):

A big part of what makes the definition of "linearly independent" so useful is that it gives a robust notion of "basis" and "dimension": a *basis* is a linearly independent set which spans the entire vector space, and any two bases for a vector space have the same number of elements, which we call the *dimension* of the space.  Any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.  These basic facts are fantastically powerful, and (when paired with the fact that any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis) are arguably the main reason that linear algebra is such a central part of mathematics.

If you allow the zero vector to be in a linearly independent set, all of this breaks down.  You could take any basis and add the zero vector to it, so a vector space can have bases of different sizes.  Furthermore, it would no longer be true that the size of a basis determines the vector space up to isomorphism (for instance, if $K$ is your scalar field, then both $K$ and $K^2$ have a basis of size $2$, namely $\{0,1\}$ and $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$).

In a certain sense, allowing the zero vector to be in a linearly independent set is much like considering the integer $1$ to be prime: the purpose of primes is to be able to factor other numbers into them, but if you allow $1$ to be prime these factorizations are no longer unique, because you can add in as many copies of $1$ as you like.  Similarly, any vector space can be "factored" into a basis (or more abstractly, split as a direct sum of simple vector spaces), but the number of terms in this factorization would not be unique if zero could be a basis element.

Comment: Thanks Eric.. This is the perfect explanation. You have actually answered what I was looking for... :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider a set of vectors **A1**,**A2**, ... ,**An**
Let A1 be the null vector, i.e. **A1**= **0**
Now consider the linear combination:
**Y**=*x1* **A1**+*x2* **A2**+....+*xn* **An** , where *x1*, *x2*,  ..., *xn* are scalars.
By definition, for the vectors to be linearly independent, **Y**=**0** if and only if *x1*=*x2*=...=*xn*=0.
However, let x1 not be equal to zero and *x2*=*x3*=....=*xn*=0
Then **Y**=*x1* **A1**=**0**
Hence they can't be linearly independent!

[Have a look at this video:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFTpc7DqyIM)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)